# Kendo Slider Change event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo slider as below

```
@(Html.Kendo().Slider()
          .Name("FixedSlider")
          .Min(0)
          .Max(10000)
          .SmallStep(100)
          .LargeStep(1000)
          .Events(events => events
              .Change("FixedSliderChange"))

          .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "temperature", @style = "width:500px" }))
        <script>
            function FixedSliderChange(e) {
              //change event 
            }
        </script>
```

Somewhere else in the code I reset the slider as below.

```
$("#FixedSlider").data("kendoSlider").trigger("slide", { value: 0 });
```

and after that slider change event is not firing anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the reset code as below and it started working as expected.

```
$("#FixedSlider").data("kendoSlider").value(0);
```